# Explain affirmative to interrogative in Present Simple

Tags: grammar

I am trying to find a good, correct explanation for how to change the sentence from an affirmative to an interrogative in the Present Simple tense, for instance:

- I am a boy. = Am I a boy?
- He eats meat. = Does he eat meat?
- We sleep at night. = Do we sleep at night?
- You are his friend. = Are you his friend?

Why in some cases it is "to be" and in others the modal verb "do"?

I know how it works, but I can't explain.

Comment: Are you familiar with subject-verb inversion in interrogative clauses?

Comment: @user105719 Yes, but that won't explain why with "to be" we don't add a helping verb whereas with other we do. "Eats he meat?" is absolutely incorrect, as much as "Do am I a boy?"

Comment: Of course not. There are no good answers to why questions about idioms. The dummy *do* is not available for the verb *to be*, possibly because of that verb's role as an auxiliary. "Eats he meet?" is archaic, not "absolutely incorrect." Check out Luke. 22:46 in the KJV: "Why sleep ye?"